# Proof: f total differentiable then f continuous

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

I'd like to show that if $f: O \subseteq \mathbb{R} n \to \mathbb{R}m$ is differentiable in $x_o \in O$, then $f$ is continuous in $x_o$.

My idea:

If $f$ is (total) differentiable in $x_o$ then there exists a linear function $T$ and a function $r(x)$ so that:

- $r(x) = ||f(x) - f(x_0) - T(x-x_0)||$ with $\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{r(x)}{||x-x_0||} = 0$.

(this follows from definition of 'differentiable')

- Now let $(y_k)$ be a series in $O$ with $(y_k) \to x_0$ for $k \to \infty$.
- Set $x_k = y_k - x_0$ so we get:
- $\lim_{k \to \infty} f(y_k) = \lim_{k \to \infty} f(x_k+x_0) = \lim_{k \to \infty} (f(x_0) + T(x_k + x_0 - x_0) + r(x_k+x_0)) = f(x_0) + 0(?) + \frac{r(x_k+x_0)}{||x_k||} \cdot ||x_k|| $

We know that $\frac{r(x_k+x_0)}{||(x_k+x_0)-x_0||}$ converges to $0$ (see above).

Do we know that $T(x_k)$ converges to $0$ as well?!

If yes, then we have $lim_{k \to \infty} f(y_k) = f(x_0)$. Then the function should be continuous (??).

Kind regards for your assistance :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think you overcomplicated it. Write: $$f(x_0+h) = f(x_0) + {\rm d}f_{x_0}(h) + r(h), \quad\mbox{with}\quad \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{r(h)}{\|h\|} = 0.$$

In particular, $\lim_{h \to 0} r(h) = 0$ (why?).
In finite dimensional vector spaces, all linear mappings are continuous, so $\lim_{h \to 0} {\rm d}f_{x_0}(h) = {\rm d}f_{x_0}(0) = 0 $. Hence: $$\lim_{h \to 0} f(x_0 + h) = \lim_{h\to 0}\big(f(x_0) + {\rm d}f_{x_0}(h) + r(h)\big) = f(x_0) + 0 + 0 = f(x_0),$$ and $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$, there exists a matrix $A$ such that

$$f(x) = f(x_0) + A(x - x_0) + o(\|x - x_0\|).$$

Since $\|A(x - x_0)\| \le \|A\|\|x - x_0\| \to 0$ as $x \to x_0$ and $$\lim_{x\to x_0} o(\|x - x_0\|) = \lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{o(\|x - x_0\|)}{\|x - x_0\|} \|x - x_0\| = \lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{o(\|x - x_0\|)}{\|x - x_0\|}\cdot \lim_{x\to x_0} \|x - x_0\| = 0,$$

we deduce $f(x) \to f(x_0)$ as $x \to x_0$. So $f$ is continuous at $x_0$.

Comment: What exactly is $o$ ? And why exactly do I have the steps in your second line (multiplying the fraction with $||x-x_0||$?)

Comment: We say $g(x) = o(\|x - x_0\|)$ as $x \to x_0$ if $\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{g(x)}{\|x - x_0\|} = 0$.

Comment: But from the equation $\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{||f(x)-f(x_0)-A\cdot(x-x_0)||}{||x-x_0||} = 0$ (in words: f is differentiable) your $o$ should the Zero in n-dimensional, or am I wrong? If not, what is this symbol?

Comment: Sorry, when I wrote $\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{g(x)}{\|x - x_0\|} = 0$, I mean't to write $\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{\|g(x)\|}{\|x - x_0\|} = 0$.